# Why socket fails in bind after having a listenfd with same port?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Simple code first:

```
#include  "NetFunc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
void test()
{
    // SOCKET listenfd = OpenListenFD("127.0.0.1", "19287");
    
    SOCKET connfd = OpenClientFD("127.0.0.1", "12389", "127.0.0.1", "19287");
    send(connfd, "test", 5, 0);
    close(connfd);
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    connfd = OpenClientFD("127.0.0.1", "12389", "127.0.0.1", "19287");
    send(connfd, "test2", 6, 0);
    close(connfd);
    // close(listenfd);
    cout << "over" << endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    SOCKET listenfd = OpenListenFD("127.0.0.1", "12389");
    sockaddr_storage clientaddr;
    socklen_t clientlen = sizeof clientaddr;
    // SOCKET connfd = 0;

    const int maxNameLen = 0x800;
    char* buffer = new char[0x800 + 1];
    char* hostname = new char[maxNameLen + 1], * port = new char[maxNameLen + 1];
    std::thread newThread{&test};
    newThread.detach();

    SOCKET connfd;
    while (true)
    {
        if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &clientlen)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Not accept correctly at InteractWithClients" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&clientaddr, clientlen, hostname, maxNameLen, port, maxNameLen, NI_NUMERICHOST);
            std::string completeAddr = string(hostname) + ":" + string(port);
            std::cout << "Addr : " << completeAddr << std::endl;
            recv(connfd, buffer, 0x800, 0);
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        close(connfd);
    }
    
    delete[] buffer; delete[] hostname; delete[]port;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `NetFunc.h` has necessary headers and `#define SOCKET int`. It corresponds with `NetFunc.cpp`, which has two functions for server&client as below:

(Note that I'm trying to generate a client with a specific port, for I just need two address-port to connect rather than to distinguish a server from a client. Besides, I already use `SO_REUSEADDR`.)

```
#include "NetFunc.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

SOCKET OpenListenFD(const char* addr, const char* port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, * listp, * p;
    SOCKET listenfd;
    int optval = 1;

    /* Get a list of potential server addresses */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;             /* Accept connections */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_ADDRCONFIG; /* ... on any IP address */

    hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICSERV;            /* ... using port number */
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    getaddrinfo(addr, port, &hints, &listp);

    /* Walk the list for one that we can bind to */
    for (p = listp; p; p = p->ai_next) {
        /* Create a socket descriptor */
        if ((listenfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) < 0)
            continue;  /* Socket failed, try the next */

        /* Eliminates "Address already in use" error from bind */
        setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,    //line:netp:csapp:setsockopt
            (setsockopt_ptr)&optval, sizeof(int)); 

        /* Bind the descriptor to the address */
        if (bind(listenfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)
        {
            break; /* Success */
        }
        closesocket(listenfd); /* Bind failed, try the next */
    }

    /* Clean up */
    freeaddrinfo(listp);
    if (!p) /* No address worked */
        return -1;

    /* Make it a listening socket ready to accept connection requests */
    if (listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0) {
        closesocket(listenfd);
        return -1;
    }
    return listenfd;

}

SOCKET OpenClientFD(const char* serverAddr, const char* port, const char* localAddr, const char* localPort)
{
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, my_addr1;
    SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client < 0)
        std::cerr<<"Error in client creating\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Client Created\n";
    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,    //line:netp:csapp:setsockopt
        (setsockopt_ptr)&optval, sizeof(int));

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));

    // This ip address will change according to the machine
    inet_pton(AF_INET, serverAddr, &my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    // Explicitly assigning port number 12010 by
    // binding client with that port
    my_addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    my_addr1.sin_port = htons(atoi(localPort));

    // This ip address will change according to the machine
    inet_pton(AF_INET, localAddr, &my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr);

    if (bind(client, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == 0)
        std::cout << "Binded Correctly\n";
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to bind\n";
        return -1;
    }
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof my_addr;
    int con = 0;
    do { con = connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof my_addr); } while (con != 0);
    if (con == 0)
        std::cout << "Client Connected\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Error in Connection\n";
    return client;
}
```

My OS is Ubuntu20.04 and such code will work with normal output. However, when I remove comments in `test()` for `listenfd`, it will output `Unable to bind` infinitely.

I'm really a newbie in socket and network. I have no idea why that will happen. Also, is there a way for an address-port to be both server and client at the same time? (Maybe to be exact, can an address-port both connect actively & accept others' connection passively?) Thank you!

Comment: A guess ... You open a server side socket as the first thing in `main` with `OpenListenFD`. Then, you create a thread that does a client side open. Just because the return value from `OpenListenFD` is a stack variable `listenfd` doesn't mean that the thread is _not_ holding it open. (i.e.) the thread should close `listenfd` but it can't because it has no access to it. You've got similar interactions.

Comment: Usually, we have a separate server and client program. For this test, I'd have `main` do two `fork` calls, one for server, one for client. Then, have the parent do `wait` for both. (e.g.) `if (fork() == 0) doserver(); if (fork() == 0) doclient();` Then, the server and client are in separate _processes_ and the test program is more like a true client/server setup.

Comment: Why are you specifying a local address and port when connecting? This is unnecessary, and is causing your problem.

Comment: @user207421 Well, actually my partners and I are trying to implement a consensus algorithm and each node has a certain port so that we can debug it with the same address `127.0.0.1`. We don't realize that a node may not be able to connect with other nodes when it has listened until we've finished most of our work. We previously let nodes with smaller IDs be servers and larger be clients, so when reconnecting, working nodes with larger IDs should act as clients to connect the reconnecting nodes with smaller IDs.

Comment: Sounds like the cure is worse than the disease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    my_addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    my_addr1.sin_port = htons(atoi(localPort));

    // This ip address will change according to the machine
    inet_pton(AF_INET, localAddr, &my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr);

    if (bind(client, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == 0)
        std::cout << "Binded Correctly\n";
```

This code binds a listening socket to port 19287, `localPort` is 19287.

```
  // SOCKET listenfd = OpenListenFD("127.0.0.1", "19287");
```

And so does the commented-out code. Un-commenting it out results in two sockets attempting to listen on the same port. Surprise, surprise: this doesn't work.

The fact that the first socket that binds this port uses `SO_REUSEADDR` is irrelevant, and makes no difference. With or without `SO_REUSEADDR`, no two sockets can listen on the same port.

`SO_REUSEADDR` ***does not*** allow you to have multiple sockets listening on the same port, at the same time. All that `SO_REUSEADDR` does is allow a listening socket to be bound on a port that's temporarily "take out of commission", in specific edge cases, until a prescribed timeout expires. It allows a port to be bound as long as nothing else is listening on it, even if it's sitting in a "timeout room".

But it still won't allow you to have two different sockets listening on the same port, at the same time.

Comment: It does make sense! So is there a way for an address-port to be both server and client at the same time?

Comment: Only one socket can be bound to the same port, at the same time. There are no alternatives to this. On a multihomed machine one can bind one socket to a port on one IP address, and bind another socket to the same port on a different IP address, that's the most that can be done.